# How to fix the open redirect issue in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, fortify

I am trying to fix the open redirect issue generated from fortify scan for the below line of code:

```
            this.Response.Redirect(string.Format("frmProducts.aspx?d={0}&i={1}", this.ddlDepartments.SelectedValue, this.ProductId.ToString()), true);
```

I tried putting a validation but it didn't work as below:

```
  if(this.ddlDepartments.SelectedValue!=null && this.ProductId.ToString()!=null)
            this.Response.Redirect(string.Format("frmProducts.aspx?d={0}&i={1}", this.ddlDepartments.SelectedValue, this.ProductId.ToString()), true);
```

Let me know if anyone know the fix for this.

Comment: what exactly you mean ? what is your issue here ? what is the error, what is not working, what you expect and not do...

Comment: Those validations do nothing at all. First of all, you use `String.Format` to convert non-string data to strings. You don't need `ProductId.ToString()` at all. If `ProductId` is null, that line will throw an exception. `this.ProductId.ToString()!=null` will throw an exception too if `ProductId` is null.

Comment: This is most likely a false positive though. A redirect vulnerability occurs when `Redirect` is called on a string that may point to an external site. That's not the case here, but the tool can't see this because of the multiple conversions. The tool *may* recognize `String.Format("frmProducts.aspx?d={0}&i={1}", ddlDepartments.SelectedValue, ProductId)`. In *any* recent ASP.NET stack (MVC, Web API, Razor Pages) it's better to use more specific redirects like `RedirectToAction` or `RedirectToPages`

Comment: If your web site uses anything except the ancient WebForms, use the appropriate method to redirect to an action or page with parameters instead of creating a URL. ASP.NET 4.5 (released in 2012) added [routing similar to MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/url-routing) which means you can now specify a route to your `Product` pages and use eg `RedirectToRoute("Product", new { i = "1", d = "widgets" });`.

Comment: this issue was resolved using some validations for string and int : 
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlVal) && Int32.TryParse(ddlVal, out val))
                    this.Response.Redirect(string.Format("frmProducts.aspx?d={0}", val), true);